# ASP.NET Web Forms give error while connecting to Oracle 11g

Tags: asp.net, oracle, dll, webforms

in my friend's laptop I have ASP.NET Web Forms (.NET 4.0) project and he is working like a charm on it. but when I copied that project to my laptop, I get this error:

```
The provider is not compatible with the version of Oracle client
```

I get the Oracle.DataAccess.dll from friend's laptop and add it to the References, Install Oracle Client 11.2.0, but the error was not gone. Oracle Client version on both laptops are same, but I downloaded my from oracle site, he installed own before. my system is Windows 8.1 Pro, x64.

Comment: Try installing the 32 bit version.

Comment: 32 bit what? Oracle client? if so, there is already a 32 bit client

Comment: Yeah, the 32 bit client. We had issues until we installed it, even though we were on a 64 bit machine. It can be a pain matching providers.

Comment: Do you have copy local = true on the reference?